# How can I resolve this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory?

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I am having an issue with reading my file. I am trying to read a CSV file in my C drive in Jupyter Notebook. I use Ubuntu to open Jupyter. My code is as below:

```
df_train = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Hotdogs/Documents/Kaggle/Tensorflow - Help Protect the Great Barrier Reef")
```

The error is:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fb738eece70f> in <module>
----> 1 df_train = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Hotdogs/Documents/Kaggle/Tensorflow - Help Protect the Great Barrier Reef")
      2 df_train['pos'] = df_train.annotations != '[]'

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    678     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    679 
--> 680     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    681 
    682 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    573 
    574     # Create the parser.
--> 575     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    576 
    577     if chunksize or iterator:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    932 
    933         self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
--> 934         self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
    935 
    936     def close(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1216             # "Union[str, PathLike[str], ReadCsvBuffer[bytes], ReadCsvBuffer[str]]"
   1217             # , "str", "bool", "Any", "Any", "Any", "Any", "Any"
-> 1218             self.handles = get_handle(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
   1219                 f,
   1220                 mode,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    784         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    785             # Encoding
--> 786             handle = open(
    787                 handle,
    788                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Hotdogs/Documents/Kaggle/Tensorflow - Help Protect the Great Barrier Reef'
```

Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `C:/Users/Hotdogs/Documents/Kaggle/Tensorflow...` is the correct path? I use Ubuntu, but don't have a path starting with `C:/...`.

Comment: You're trying to read a CSV file, but I see no CSV file in your path. Should `.csv` be placed at the end of "Tensorflow - Help Protect the Great Barrier Reef" ?

Comment: @MichaelS. Even when I replaced it with 'C:/Users/Hotdogs/Documents/Kaggle/Tensorflow - Help Protect the Great Barrier Reef/train.csv', it still did not work.

Comment: @j1-lee. I read the CSV file in Jupyter Notebook, not in the powershell command line.

Comment: Realistically, the most likely solution here is that the path to the file is inaccurate. Try placing `r` in front of your directory, i.e. `r'C:/Users/Hotdogs/Documents/Kaggle/Tensorflow - Help Protect the Great Barrier Reef/train.csv'`, triple check that your above directory is correct and that the file is there, and if none of this works, try changing some of your folder names to something more simple

Comment: Also, maybe update your question with a picture of your folder and its path like so: [my folder](https://i.imgur.com/ceGgCIn.png) <- Using this directory, I had no issues so I cannot recreate your problem.

Comment: @MichaelS.Thank you for your suggestion to place r in front of the directory. I tried and it did not work. Do you think I need to mount my c drive?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using the pathlib library and providing an absolute path. It should work for Linux and Windows.

If pandas requires the path as a string. You can just cast the path instance to string.

If you give me a view of your file-structure I may be able to provide more assistance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Dario. Thank you for your comment. Here is my file structure: ibb.co/5cN4PS6